# Error while uploading apk on playstore

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

getting following error while uploading apk on playstore, please help.

> deactivation of this apk will result into your app being available for
>   new installs on fewer types of devices.

Thank you.

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Do you upload it via website or gradle script?

Comment: @mklimek i am trying to upload it via google playstore console

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This message is a warning which says that your new apk will be available for a fewer number of devices.

The reason is, you made changes which probably affected `AndroidManifest.xml`. You could add new permissions, feature, screen support etc. So this message will be helpful when you added one of them by mistake and you would make apk available for fewer people (who would like to do that by mistake?).

Go through your code changes (comparing to the previous build) to check what exactly makes this limitation happened.

In most of the cases it's **totally fine**, because it's just natural that during the development process, you request more regarding system or device and as a result, it will run on a smaller number of devices.

You can ignore this warning and go ahead with publishing if you're aware what you're doing.

Comment: i have also having this warning when i try to upload new apk. only thing in manifest i added is some activity nothing else, no camera or hardware related permission is not used you can see my manifest and gradel in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399513/device-support-removed-warning-comming-when-updating-app-on-playstore-android

Comment: i search the whole web for a solution, no use all say the similar thing like screen support or feature new permisson, but nothing new added not even a new library only added some ativity and when upload it showing warning

Comment: What should i do in this case i am getting same issue since last 1 week and App is not approving in play store