# Android rollout is blocked due to "Device support removed" warning

Tags: android, google-play

Im trying to rollout a new beta release of an android app.

I have uploaded the apk file to the Google Play console.

But in the release page I get the following warning:
[image: Device support removed]

While it says it is just a warning, I am unable to proceed with the rollout.

And as there are no other errors or warnings, I'm assuming the reason I cannot continue is due to this warning.

This app is only installed on 2 devices - the developers devices. The warning has no real consequences, as the app is in beta.

Is there anyone way to get passed this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099110/3789993

Comment: Thanks, yes I had seen that, but apparently I cannot just ignore the warning and proceed. I am blocked. The Start Rollout to Beta button is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Same things happened to me with the version code 2. so I built and uploaded new apk with version code 3. Don't know how but it did work!

Answer (score 1):

The rollout could be blocked because other parts of the app info you need to fill in are not complete.

**On the left panel, make sure all the check marks are green.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't block your rollout. If it is blocking your rollout, or something else is and the Play console isn't telling you what it is, then it is a bug in the Play Console. Please contact the Play Console support (using the Contact section under the help "?" icon) and they can check your exact details and work out what is going wrong. They can provide support using email and live chat.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when migrated to androidx.

The numbers of affected devices for the new version was insignificant. (1 device out of 7000+)
I decided to continue with the rollout in spite of this warning.